# Unexpected errors

Tags: java, stack

I have a school project I'm not supposed to be starting til monday, and it's not due for another 6 weeks or longer. We are creating a program in java to add what we want to a database, I chose games (title, genre, platform, price, quantity(string, combobox, combobox, double, int)), I'm using a stack to add all of the objects to, but for some reason I can't get it to compile for some reason, and I keep getting really strange errors. My error and then code are below respectively.

```
nathan@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TAFE/Jeff (Java)/personalProject$ javac *.java
GameCombo.java:11: <identifier> expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                   ^
GameCombo.java:11: illegal start of type
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                    ^
GameCombo.java:11: ')' expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                       ^
GameCombo.java:11: ';' expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                            ^
GameCombo.java:11: illegal start of type
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                             ^
GameCombo.java:11: <identifier> expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                            ^
GameCombo.java:11: ';' expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                             ^
GameCombo.java:11: illegal start of type
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                               ^
GameCombo.java:11: <identifier> expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                                ^
GameCombo.java:11: <identifier> expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                                   ^
GameCombo.java:11: illegal start of type
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                                          ^
GameCombo.java:11: <identifier> expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                                           ^
GameCombo.java:11: ';' expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                                             ^
GameCombo.java:11: illegal start of type
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                                              ^
GameCombo.java:11: <identifier> expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                                               ^
GameCombo.java:11: ';' expected
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
                                                                ^
16 errors

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GameCombo extends JPanel {
  ArrayList<Game> gamesList = new ArrayList<Game>();
  Stack<Game> gamesStack = new Stack<Game>();
    gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
    //gamesList.add(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
    //gamesList.add(new Game("[Dead Space]", "Xbox 360", "Horror", "$68.00", "1"));

  //String[] games = {"", "[Halo: Reach] Xbox 360; Action; $108.00; 2;", "[Dead Space] Xbox 360; Horror; $65.00; 1;"}; 
  private JComboBox _gameBox = new JComboBox(gamesStack);

    public GameCombo() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,1,1));

        add(_gameBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: It was there, but some guy deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call:

```
gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
```

should be in some method, since you want to do it i every new object, as it looks from your code, why not moving it to the constructor:

```
public class GameCombo extends JPanel {
  ArrayList<Game> gamesList = new ArrayList<Game>();
  Stack<Game> gamesStack = new Stack<Game>();
  private JComboBox _gameBox;

    public GameCombo() {
         setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,1,1));
         gamesStack.push(new Game("[Halo: Reach]", 3, 1, 108.00, 2));
         _gameBox = new JComboBox(gamesStack);
         add(_gameBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: Man I hate it when I do stupid mistakes like this; all part of the learning process I guess. Thank you, good sir! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to first define a method and then write the relevant code within the method . I am not disclosing much as this is a home work project . Try reading up more on java's classes and methods

Answer (score 1):

You can't have your code directly in the classbody, you must put it into a method or constructor.